# default color palette for Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a custom color palette i created for my employer

```
pink = '#E5007E'
pink_80 = '#FFC7E6'
pink_60='#FF8FCC'
aqua='#00B4DF'
aqua_80='#C6F4FF'
pink_40='#FF56B3'
pink_d25='#AC005F'
aqua_60='#8CE9FF'
aqua_40='#53DEFF'
aqua_d25='#0087A7'

color_list = [pink, aqua,
              aqua_80, pink_80,aqua_60, pink_60,aqua_40,pink_40,aqua_d25,pink_d25]
```

how do i make this the default color palette for all charts going forward? Is there such a way of saying "import color_list" and have matplotlib default to that list?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701464/how-to-set-matplotlib-colormap-as-color-palette-in-seaborn

Comment: Or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404913/how-to-change-the-color-palette-for-stackplot-matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify Matplotlib's configuration file, `matplotlibrc`. This file is stored on various locations, depending on the level you wish to apply your edits (globally, vs single environment). You can find the locations at this [documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files)

Once you have located the file to modify, you open it and look for this line:

```
#axes.prop_cycle: cycler('color', ['1f77b4', 'ff7f0e', '2ca02c', 'd62728', '9467bd', '8c564b', 'e377c2', '7f7f7f', 'bcbd22', '17becf'])
```

You need to remove the first character `#`, and copy the hex values without the `#` character, like this:

```
axes.prop_cycle: cycler('color', ['E5007E', '00B4DF', 'C6F4FF', 'FFC7E6', '8CE9FF', 'FF8FCC', '53DEFF', 'FF56B3', '0087A7', 'AC005F'])
```

Save the file, open a Python interpreter:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)
plt.figure()
for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x, (i + 1) * np.cos(x), label=str(i))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, the new color palette is going to be used everytime you load matplotlib.